Is there a quick way to reclaim space overallocated for files on ext4?
Samba 3 has somehow overallocated a lot of space on my NAS for hundreds of files. (Looks like that was caused by strict allocate = yes in smb.conf even though it's unclear to me why. Filesystem is ext4 and I didn't have problems before, but it has been bugged in specific file copy scenario.)
# ls -lh Pictures/Screenshot/cr_code.jpg
-rw-rw-r--    1 cat      nas        77.8K May  7 17:23 Pictures/Screenshot/cr_code.jpg
# du -h Pictures/Screenshot/cr_code.jpg
80.0M   Pictures/Screenshot/cr_code.jpg

Is it normal for ext4 that it does not free the overallocated space after file is written and closed? Reboot did not change that, e2fsck also, truncate on files helps.
Is there a better way to clean it up than writing a script with truncate and running it over the whole system?


Is there a better way to clean it up than writing a script with truncate and running it over the whole system?

Write a short command with truncate and run it over whatever you want. This example will try to apply truncate -s +0 to regular files in the current working directory and below.
find . -type f -exec truncate -s +0 {} +

(Append -print to see pathnames.)

Thanks for +0 and {} +, I missed those features. Bonus question: how could I instead just find all the files which really require truncating? I don't want to reset all modification times unnecessarily.

Still, this likely requires some precautions to avoid accidental concurrent access to the files.
